# What does this() represent?

Tags: c#, constructor

```
public wndWallet( Subscriber editsubscriber, msoServiceType msoServiceTypeMode ) : this()
{
    tempsubscriber = editsubscriber;
    this.msoServiceTypeMode = msoServiceTypeMode;
}
```

Comment: An overload constructor call.

Comment: @UweKeim Sorry, my bad. Thought it is `base()` for some reason :)

Answer (score 2):

`this()` calls the parameter-less constructor for the same class.